# Get & apply setting (e.g. color) from another indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am creating multiple indicators - ideally to be used together.

Since many levels share the same coloring, I was wondering if I can

- get the color a user may specify in the "main" indicator for e.g. "open" line
- and re-use the same color on the second ("sub") indicator

I couldnt find it in the docs. **Any hint?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `input` from one indicator on another indicator. In some cases, you can use indicator output to another indicator using [indicator on indicator function](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/new-feature-8211-apply-an-indicator-to-another-indicator-1844/).

After saying that, you can do nice things with [libraries](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Libraries.html) in pine script. While you can't get inputs between two indicators, with libraries you can have the same input to all the indicators that imports this library.

You can even do a choosable color palette if you wish:

```
//@version=5
library("ChartColors", true)

export colorOfChart(string palette) =>

    color colorOfBackgroung = na
    color colorOfCandle = na
    
    if palette == "purple/white"
        colorOfBackgroung := color.new(color.purple, 90)
        colorOfCandle := close > open ? color.purple : color.white
    
    else if palette == "green/red"
        colorOfBackgroung := color.new(color.green, 90)
        colorOfCandle := close > open ? color.green : color.red
    
    [colorOfBackgroung, colorOfCandle]
```

And than import the library to your code:

```
//@version=5
import usrname/ChartColors/2 as colors

indicator("My script", overlay=true)

palette = input.string(defval="green/red", title="Chosse color palette", options=["green/red", "purple/white"])

[bgColor, candleColor] = colors.colorOfChart(palette)

bgcolor(bgColor)
barcolor(candleColor)

plot(close)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I flag this is correct/right answer, even though libraries is not what solves my "issue" with having users to enter reduntant information. Still might be helpful for others looking at this. Thanks for sharing.